# How can I Run docker CMD command as an unprivileged user?

Tags: node.js, docker, puppeteer

I'm trying to dockerize my app that requires puppeteer but I get the following error when running my app:

```sh
Launching Browser
/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:229
reject(new Error([

^

Error: Failed to launch the browser process!

[0204/174647.675714:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(90)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.



TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md

at onClose (/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:229:20)
at Interface.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:219:68)
at Interface.emit (node:events:402:35)
at Interface.close (node:readline:586:8)
at Socket.onend (node:readline:277:10)
at Socket.emit (node:events:402:35)
at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1343:12)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

And here's my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .

# Do stuff that puppeteer requires for some reason
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y wget gnupg \
    && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-kacst fonts-freefont-ttf libxss1 \
      --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
    
# Insall other deps
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y imagemagick ghostscript
RUN npm ci
CMD ["node","index.js"]
```

What do I need to do to get the CMD command of the dockerfile to run as an unprivileged user? I've already tried to enable `no-sandbox` on my browser

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        defaultViewport: { width: 1920, height: 1080 },
        headless: true,
        args:['no-sandbox']
    });
```

Comment: [`USER`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user)

Answer (score 1):

All of the current statements in your `Dockerfile` are executed by the root user. You should define the [USER](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user) instruction specifying a non-root user before the targeted instructions. You can use [USER](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user) multiple times in a `Dockerfile` as needed.

In a `node` image, typically the eponymous `node` user is available; hence your `Dockerfile` could look as follows to run `CMD` with the non-root `node` user:

```
[..]

# Insall other deps
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y imagemagick ghostscript
RUN npm ci
USER node
CMD ["node","index.js"]
```

Comment: I ended up creating a user per the troubleshooting page but I'm getting an error now where puppeteer says `no useable sandbox! update your kernel or see ...`

Comment: Of course you can create a user yourself but most times you can get away with the `node` user and less effort. Your sandbox error most likely does not relate to your initial question, so please create another post if needed.